# Inject CSS into <webview> Chrome/Electron/HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webview, electron

Can anyone tell me why the below wont work? Please forgive any mistakes I am new to all of this

HTML

```
    <webview id="wv1" src="https://www.github.com/" style="display:inline-flex; width:100%; height:140px" nodeintegration></webview>



    <script>
    var webview = document.getElementById('wv1');
    webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', function() {
    webview.insertCSS('html,body{ background-color: #FF0000 !important;}')
    });

    </script>
```

I'm trying to get it so that once the content within the webview has loaded the background is changed to red via CSS. Open to any alternatives or help with why the above wont work.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me using the following setup, basically just the electron [quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md)

Run as `electron index.js`

[image: Result]

## index.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let win

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

## index.html

```
<webview id="wv1" src="https://www.github.com/" style="display:inline-flex; width:100%; height:140px" nodeintegration></webview>

<script>
    var webview = document.getElementById('wv1');
    webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', function () {
        webview.insertCSS('html,body{ background-color: #FF0000 !important;}')
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure you may want to use instead of dom-ready the DOMContentLoaded and instead of insertCss, insertRule.

```
var webview = document.getElementById('wv1');

webview.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   webview.insertRule('html,body{ background-color: #FF0000 !important;}',1)
 });
```

However, if it won't work you may want to try

```
webview.querySelector(body) !== null
```

Inside the function.

hope it works.